# If f is integrable on $[a,b]$, prove $f^{q}$ is integrable on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $q $ be a rational number. Suppose that $a < b,\ 0 < c < d $, and that $f : [a,b] $->$ [c,d] $. If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then prove that $f^{q}$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.

I think that the proof involves the binomial theorem. My book has a proof showing that $f^2$ is integrable if $f$ is integrable, which I assume can be easily extended to $f^n$ for any integer $n$. I'm not sure exactly how to go about it from there though.

Comment: Have you proven Hölder's inequality?

Comment: @nik No, not that I'm aware of

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

1. $f$ is Riemann integrable and $g$ is continuous then the composition $g \circ f$ -- when this makes sense --is Riemann integrable (Theorem 8.18 of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf)).
2. If $f: [a,b] \rightarrow [c,d]$ is continuous and monotone, then the inverse function $f^{-1}$ exists and is continuous (Theorem 5.39 of [*loc. cit.*](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf)).

Alternately, as with so many of these kinds of results, this is an immediate corollary of Lebesgue's Criterion for Riemann Integrability (Theorem 8.28 of [*loc. cit.*](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf)).  In fact this latter route takes care of irrational exponents as well.